# Dynamics CRM 4.0 - Editing reports

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

We've created a number of reports using the Wizard in CRM 4.0. Whilst the functionality on them is perfect the layout could be greatly improved. For example they spill onto two pages wide and a lot of space is wasted.

I know we can export the raw .rdl files but what is the best way to edit these visually to try and improve the layout. I tried using Visual Studio 2010 but it only opens them as XML. Is that the only way to edit them or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To edit CRM 4.0 reports you need to use BIDS (Business Development Intelligence Studio).
You can use Visual Studio 2005, I don't know if Visual Studio 2008 is compatible with CRM 4.0 rdl (but maybe with recent updates yes)

check this tutorial:
[http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.it/2008/12/dynamics-crm-report-modification.html](http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.com/2008/12/dynamics-crm-report-modification.html)